How would you sort a column after applying regex and also move all null values to the end using Python and Pyspark?
I currently apply basic asc/desc sort to a column in Python like this:
sort_exprs = [(col.asc() if direction == "asc" else col.desc())]
sorted_dataframe = dataframe.orderBy(*sort_exprs)

One of my columns has data in the format
+-----------------+
|       columnName|
+-----------------+
|           10 (5)|
|             null|
|          15 (20)|
+-----------------+

I'd like to:

regardless of what type of sort I use, if a column is being sorted, always move the rows with a null value for that column to the end
have the option of sorting by the number in the parentheses. In the example above, I'd sort 5 and 20 instead of 10 and 15. The regex to get the number in the parentheses is r"\((\d+(\.\d+)?)\)"

How would I do this? Thank you in advance

You can use when() and isNull():
direction = "asc"
df = df.withColumn("par", regexp_extract(col("columnName"), r"\((\s*[0-9]+\s*)\s*\)", 1).cast("double"))
sort_exprs = [
    when(col("columnName").isNull(), 1).otherwise(0).asc(),
    (col("par").asc() if direction == "asc" else col("par").desc())
]

sorted_df = df.orderBy(*sort_exprs).drop("par")


Note
This pattern \((\s*[0-9]+\s*)\s*\) works, even if there might be spaces inside the pars.

Without adding a new column:
direction = "asc"
RE = regexp_extract(col("columnName"), r"\((\s*[0-9]+\s*)\s*\)", 1).cast("double")
sort_exprs = [
    when(col("columnName").isNull(), 1).otherwise(0).asc(),
    (RE.asc() if direction == "asc" else RE.desc())
]

sorted_df = df.orderBy(*sort_exprs)


Thank you  Is there a way to do this without adding a new column?
